# Laravel Forge Does Not Run Scheduled Command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-forge, laravel-scheduler

Something is wrong with command running on Laravel Forge via their scheduler.
I have plenty of commands there already and all of hthem are running just fine. Scheduler setup is generic, it calls `artisan schedule:run` every minute and everything is fine with existing commands.

However, I added a new one and registered it in the scheduler (in the Console/Kernel)

```
$schedule->command('new-command-signature')
            ->daily()
            ->between('22:00', '23:00');
```

Also registered the command class name in the Kernel `$commands` property.

And - nothing. It is not picked up and not triggered.

I have another command registered besides the new one with very similar config

```
$schedule->command('another-command')
            ->daily()
            ->between('23:00', '1:00');
```

And it keeps working like a charm.

I didn't have such issues before, commands were picked up just fine. Are there any ways to address this issue?

What I tried already:

1. restarting the scheduler
2. clearing the app cache and the scheduler cache

Answer (score 0):

Probably there's a bug with `between('XX:YY', 'ZZ:WW');` definition when multiple schedules are defined. My config had this for 2 commands, and though schedules were not clashing, the command registered earlier was ignored.

So I managed to fix this by removing `between` on my command which wasn't running. Now it is working fine.